# How to pass "args" while using Intellij IDEA [example list 3.11 in Odersky's Scala book (2nd Ed)]

Tags: bash, scala, intellij-idea

I basically try to run the example 3.11 in Odersky's book (Programming in Scala). I am using Intellij IDE. While runing the code, the "else" branch got executed.
The screen capture is here:
[image]

The source is here in case you need it to try:

```
package ch3

import scala.io.Source

object l3p11 extends App{
  def widthOfLength(s: String) = s.length.toString.length

  if (args.length > 0){
    val lines = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().toList
    val longestLine = lines.reduceLeft(
      (a, b) => if (a.length > b.length) a else b
    )
    val maxWidth = widthOfLength(longestLine)
    for (line <- lines){
      val numSpaces = maxWidth - widthOfLength(line)
      val padding = " " * numSpaces
      println(padding + line.length + "|" + line)
    }
  }
  else
    Console.err.println("Please enter filename")
}
```

The reason, I think, is becuase I did not pass args correctly (say here I want to pass the source file l3p11.scala as the args). I tried several option, but have not find a way to pass the args correctly for the code to be executed in the "if" branch. There are two directions in my mind to resolve this problem:
1. Find the right way to pass args in Intellij IDE

2. Run Scala in commond line, a similar command such as

   $ scala l3p11.scala l3p11.scala

should be able to pass the args correctly. But my current setting gives "bash: scala: command not found". I currently use scala REPL to run scala code following the set up given in Odersky's [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/home/info) course on Scala. I think I need to change the set up in orde run scala directly, instead of using "sbt->console" to invoke the scala interpreter like what I am doing now.

Any suggestion on either direction (or other directions that I have not thought of) to resolve the problem is welcome.

**Update 1:**
Direction 2 works after I reinstall scala. (My to be corrected understanding is that the installation of sbt does not provide an executable binary of scala to be included in the environment list for Windows. Therefore, scala command cannot be found before). After installation of scala directly:

> $ scala l3p11.scala l3p11.scala

gives the expected results. But I still have not figured out how to get this result with Intellij IDEA.

**Update 2:**
I revisited the "Program arguments" option after Joe's confirmation. The reason I was not be able to get it work before was that I only add "l3p11.scala". Adding the complete path from working directory "src/main/scala/ch3/l3p11.scala" solved the problem. The result is as following:
[image]

Comment: I found Intellij adds a ; after run when i use the sbt shell for the "sbt task", so i just switched to VS Code + Metals.
Have had no problem running.
Command line\terminal also is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass command-line arguments when running a program in IntelliJ IDEA, use the "Edit Configurations …" menu item under "Run".  Choose the entry for your main program.  There's a "Program arguments" text field where you specify the arguments to pass to the program.

Comment: Thanks Joe, adding "src/main/scala/ch3/l3p11.scala" to program arguments solved the problem. I also edit the details in Update 2 in case it may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar on how it will run on windows but if you are able to run it directly from the command line then I think you'll need to compile first, that's the scalac command. So:

```
$ scalac l3p11.scala
```

then you can run just with the class name, not sure if you would need quotes on the arg:

```
$ scala l3p11 l3p11.scala
```

Comment: @ F.Lins, thank you for the reply. I have tried that before, and I got error like this:
scala> l3p11.scala l3p11.scala
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '.' found.
       l3p11.scala l3p11.scala
Any idea why? This is on Windows machine.